# Amount of data per node in Neo4j

Tags: nosql, neo4j

I need to store substantial amounts of data per node in Neo4j. The data is Unicode chunks of text. Actually not every node will have big chunks, but many of them will.

I waded through the documentation but didn't find any mention on the Node size – the amount of data a single node can contain.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: How big are your chunks in general? You should make sure to find a suitable string_block_size to keep the number of string blocks in the storage down to a reasonable level as well as not wasting too much space in only half-filled blocks. How will the data be used? Just rendered or also queried/processed otherwise? If you **need** to save space, compression + storage as byte array can be an option.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ultimately, it depends on the architecture that your machine has.

---

(background) Nodes can solely store data in their properties. Their properties are stored using a key-value store. (per [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150708221541/http://neo4j.com/api_docs/1.4/org/neo4j/graphdb/Node.html))

The value in each property is limited to Java primitives (ints, floats, etc.), strings, and arrays of primitives/strings.

Therefore, the maximum amount of data a particular *property* can hold would be limited to the maximum size for a string or the maximum size for an array of strings (that's *per node*).  This limit (for 32-bit machines) is 4GB.  (Note that this [may be limited to 2-3 GB](https://web.archive.org/web/20111231081149/http://java.sun.com/performance/reference/whitepapers/tuning.html#section4.1.2).)

(Also, having said this, there was a bug previously that [limited string size to 1 MB](http://neo4j.org/forums/#nabble-td444430).  I expect that this is resolved.)

Of course, this raises the question of whether multiple properties could store more than 4GB per node.  Since the properties list is essentially a key-value store, it would expect that the maximum size would be limited by disk space and key selection.  I can't find anything to support or deny this, however.

---

That doesn't *definitively* answer your question, but from what I understand you should be able to store **large** amounts of data per node (up to disk space capacity).